# Android: PrintAttributes.MediaSize for roll printer

Tags: android, printing

I'm wondering how to specify the argument `heightMils` in `PrintAttributes.MediaSize` for a roll printer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android already defines some large format media sizes, e.g [ISO_A2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintAttributes.MediaSize.html#ISO_A2). If you need to define your own custom size, heightMils is "the height in mils (thousandths of an inch)." Roll printers support large format media sizes, you just need to find what media sizes it supports and supply that height.

Comment: So I understand that I have to create some kind of `virtual pages` on my roll (58 mm wide, 20 m long).

Comment: As all other printers, roll printers support and reports certain media sizes. If you're using ipp (and I assume other protocols would have a similar way), this would be the [media-supported](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2911#section-4.2.11) field.